# What is the meaning of clean test -P?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

For one of the project, we are supporting I see the Maven

> clean test -P DEV,CI

inside the Goals and Options for the **build option of Jenkins**. Its is causing the Sonar analysis of the test jobs behave incorrectly.

I tried to find the meaning of -P option, but did not get any solutions so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Maven CLI Options Reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html) documents what `-P` means:

```
-P,--activate-profiles <arg>    Comma-delimited list of profiles to activate
```

It is related to **profiles**. Read more at [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: Thanks to Chad who edited my answer to make it more intelligible